How do I attach the tooltip to the Input type range slider and update the values
I have a slider with five breakpoints, as shown in the example code below. I want to attach a tooltip to the slider thumb and dynamically update the tooltip values based on a 4.25% interest for each breakpoint.
How can I achieve this? I tried with basic HTML, but seems like it may need Javascript? Or is it possible with pure CSS?
Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated!


.input-range {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 24px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #ecedee;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0
}

.input-range::-ms-track {
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border: 3px 0
}

.input-range::-ms-fill-lower {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)
}

.input-range::-ms-fill-upper {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)
}

.input-range::-ms-tooltip {
  display: none
}

.input-range::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  appearance: none;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #006fcf;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none
}

.input-range::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #006fcf;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none
}

.input-range::-ms-thumb {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #006fcf;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none
}

.input-range:focus {
  outline: #97999b dashed 1px !important;
  outline-offset: 3px
}

.values {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 10px
}

.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #008085;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  border-radius: 100px;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 68px;
}
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="tooltip">
    10,625
  </div>
  <input aria-valuenow="3898" aria-valuemin="1299" aria-valuemax="42500" type="range" class="input-range" aria-label="Interest Calculator Slider" min="0" step="1" max="4" value="1">
  <div class="values">
    <div class="value_1">$250,000 <span>(10,625)</span> </div>
    <div class="value_2">$500,000 <span>(21,250)</span> </div>
    <div class="value_3">$1,000,000 <span>(42,500)</span> </div>
    <div class="value_4">$3,000,000 <span>(1,27,500)</span> </div>
    <div class="value_5">$5,000,000 <span>(2,12,500)</span> </div>
  </div>
</div>




https://frontendmasters.com/blog/custom-range-slider-using-anchor-positioning-scroll-driven-animations/

You can use an event listener on the range and then use the ranges value as an index to query the class .value's children, then set the tooltip text after some basic formatting with in a callback method for a change eventListener.
To lock in the tooltip, you can use a helper function to track the step of the range and calculate the percentage using the inputs max attribute. Then change the left position depending on step calculated against 100% of the ranges max.
See comments in the snippet below and let me know if this is not what you were looking for.


// get elements and assign variables
const values = document.querySelector('.values');

// query the child divs in the class 'values'
const valueDivs = values.querySelectorAll('div');

// get the tooltip 
const tooltip = document.querySelector('.tooltip');

// get the input
const inputRange = document.querySelector('.input-range');

// added a method to calculate the intrest on princliple amount
// pass in interest and principle as params, 
// make sure to parse strings as Number()
const interest = 4.25;
const calculation = (p, i) => {
  return Number(p.replace(/[^0-9.]+/g, '')) * (Number(i)/100);
}

// run same code in method initially to get proper calculation of interest on principle to display in tooltip
const num = calculation(valueDivs[inputRange.value].textContent, interest)
// format using Number() and .toLocalString() and assign to tooltip textContent
tooltip.textContent = `$${Number(num).toLocaleString()}`;
// move tooltip to proper step on load
setToolTip(inputRange, tooltip);

// callback method to assign and format tooltip, pass in event
const changeValue = e => {
  // get the number using the returned value from the slider input
  // then query the values child element using the ranges index 
  // format the textContent and replace all but numbers (remove parenthesis)
  const num = calculation(valueDivs[e.target.value].textContent, interest);
 
  // format using Number() and .toLocalString() and assign to tooltip textContent
  tooltip.textContent = `$${Number(num).toLocaleString()}`;
  // helper method to move tooltip
  setToolTip(e.target, tooltip);
}

// eventListener for change on the input-range
inputRange.addEventListener('input', changeValue);

// helper function to move tooltip
function setToolTip(range, el) {
  // get range value
  const val = range.value;
  // get range max
  const max = range.max;
  // set up an offset, may need to be adjusted depending on screen size or steps added/removed.
  let offset = 1.5;
  // conditional to check last step and offset tooltip to stay within range
  if(val === max) offset += max/2;
  // set step variable using 100% divided by max steps
  let step = 100/max - (offset);
  // set left style by multiplying step by the current ranges value 
  el.style.left = `${step * val}%`;
}
.input-range {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 24px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #ecedee;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0
}

.input-range::-ms-track {
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border: 3px 0
}

.input-range::-ms-fill-lower {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)
}

.input-range::-ms-fill-upper {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)
}

.input-range::-ms-tooltip {
  display: none
}

.input-range::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  appearance: none;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #006fcf;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;  
}

.input-range::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #006fcf;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none
}

.input-range::-ms-thumb {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #006fcf;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none
}

.input-range:focus {
  outline: #97999b dashed 1px !important;
  outline-offset: 3px
}

.values {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 10px
}

.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #008085;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  border-radius: 100px;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 68px;
}
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="tooltip">
    10,625
  </div>
  <input aria-valuenow="3898" aria-valuemin="1299" aria-valuemax="42500" type="range" class="input-range" aria-label="Interest Calculator Slider" min="0" step="1" max="4" value="1">
  <div class="values">
    <div class="value_1">$250,000</div>
    <div class="value_2">$500,000</div>
    <div class="value_3">$1,000,000</div>
    <div class="value_4">$3,000,000</div>
    <div class="value_5">$5,000,000</div>
  </div>
</div>



Also there are some great examples at csstricks.com showing much more in depth and accurate code for what you are looking for.

Perfect!! thanks @dale landry...Only thing is, there is a delay in the tooltip movement then the slider thumb otherwise it works perfect.

@SathishKumar, change your eventListener to input from change and it will be instantaneous.

Perfect! It's simple and has minimal code. However, I made a mistake by including the interest number within the span tag <span>(10,625s)</span>. The interest calculation should be based on the value given in the div <div class="value_1">$250,000</div>. It seems the displayed value is the same as what I gave in the span tag, which was just for discussion. I need to remove it. By any chance calculating the div value by 4.25% interest?

Sure whats the calculation? Assuming there is no time period for say a loan or something of that nature, then principle * interest rate/100, correct?

See my updated snippet.

Amazing, Thank you so much
